# Asset precompilation with Phusion Passenger, Apache and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I get the following error when I try to access my Rails application hosted on an Apache server with Phusion Passenger providing the Rails code integration to Apache. I have run rake assets:precompile on this server so I'm not sure why I'm getting this erro (as I don't get any problems with my precompile now).

ActionView::Template::Error (twitter-icon.svg isn't precompiled):

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is `twitter-icon.svg` in your Rails app (in `/app/assets/images`?)

Comment: Yup, just in app/assets/images.

Comment: did you try adding `config.assets.precompile += %w( blueprint/print.css )` in production.rb and run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out Apache doesn't immediately recognize the asset precompilation so after you do that, you need to restart your Apache server! It works like magic!

Thanks!!

Comment: upvoted as this answer just led to my solution. Thanks